# Is it possible to test for the presence of a custom directive attribute in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-directives

For instance, I have a custom directive called `featureFlag`, which shows or hides an element depending on the configuration of that feature:

```
<div *myFeatureFlag="'myFeatureName'">
    This should be hidden if the myFeatureName feature is turned off.
</div>
```

When it comes to testing this, however, I'm at a loss.  I already know how to test the directive itself, but I want to test that `*myFeatureFlag` is added to an element, without testing the logic inside of the `myFeatureFlag` directive.

Is there a way to check for the existence of this directive in my unit test?  Something like this:

```
it('should be wrapped in a feature flag', () => {
    expect(element.querySelector('div').myFeatureFlag).toEqual("'myFeatureName'");
});
```

Comment: Did you check how they [test `*ngIf`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/common/test/directives/ng_if_spec.ts)? Maybe that will help...

Comment: The tests for *ngIf test the visibility of the element, which I specifically want to avoid here.  I simply want to test that the feature flag attribute was added without testing the resulting behaviour (as that behaviour may change at a later date).

Comment: You cannot test that. It's the template part, so angular2 remove during compilation to generate proper html. You can only test html result, not template directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an ugly way, but it works. When Angular creates the bindings, it adds some comments to the HTML

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-my-feature-flag": "myFeatureName"
}-->
```

What you can do is parse it with some regex and grab the JSON. Then just check the value

```
function getFeatureFlagBinding(el: any) {
  return JSON
    .parse((/template bindings=(\{[\s\S]*?\})/g)
      .exec(el.nativeElement.previousSibling.textContent)[1])['ng-reflect-my-feature-flag'];
}

it('should be wrapped in a feature flag', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

  let div = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(n => n.name === 'div')[0];
  expect(getFeatureFlagBinding(div)).toBe('myFeatureName');
});
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I needed.  The thing I didn't specify in my question was that I have several elements inside one component that I may need to check.  I have updated your answer to only find a specific element (and the preceding comment) rather than the first matching comment in the component.  Excellent answer otherwise!

Comment: Also refactored to use a helper function to get the value of the feature flag directive.  Made the test a bit shorter to boot.